# Restrict access for a specific forum to a specific user role

Tags: 8, nodes

I am using Drupal 8 and the core Forum module.

I have several forums on a site.

I wish to restrict access for some of the forums based on the role of the user.

eg:

```
Forum A: 'Moderator' and 'Role A' can access ('Role B cannot access')   
Forum B: 'Moderator' and 'Role B' can access ('Role A cannot access')
```

I cannot seem to find a way to do this and am having trouble finding a straight answer about how to do it online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Taxonomy Access Control Lite](https://www.drupal.org/project/tac_lite) is a good module to achieve this.

> This node_access module governs access to nodes based on the taxonomy
>   terms applied to the nodes. A simple scheme based on taxonomy, roles
>   and users controls which content is visible.
>
> As the name implies, this module shares some functionality with an
>   earlier module called Taxonomy Access Control (TAC). If you are
>   shopping around for an access control module to use, consider that one
>   as well. See this module's README.txt for an explanation of "why yet
>   another access control module".

I have implemented one of my site for same purpose.

You can also go for

[Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/tac_lite) and [ACL](https://www.drupal.org/project/acl) modules.

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by
>   role and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and
>   delete permissions for each content type. Optionally you can enable
>   per content access settings, so you can customize the access for each
>   content node.

One more Option Using [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module.

> The Group module allows you to create arbitrary collections of your
>   content and users on your site and grant access control permissions on
>   those collections
>
> Out of the box, Drupal only allows a person to view, create or edit
>   the different content types you create. However, you might want to be
>   able to let them view or edit all content types, but only in a
>   specific section of the site.